# Which way is better in PowerShell and why

Tags: powershell

I am novice in powershell and using it very rarely for some little things. 
I am using  this one liner in order to extract emails 
recursive

```
(Get-ChildItem -Include *.txt -Recurse | Get-Content | Select-String -Pattern "(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,5})").Matches | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value -Unique
```

In order to access **Matches** property I've added parentheses. Later I come to that way:

```
Get-ChildItem -Include *.txt -Recurse | Get-Content | Select-String -Pattern "(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,5})" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches -Unique | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
```

I want to to ask what parentheses  do exactly in the first version.

Comment: if you are dealing with MANY objects, then the process of building/sending/un-building things to shove across the pipeline can be slow. however, the definition of "many" is likely in the thousands ... and by that time, you may need the pipeline for the RAM savings. so ... use the one that makes the most sense to you. ///// one thing that i would change is the use of `Get-Content` - the `Select-String` cmdlet will load a file directly, so you can save a step AND a pipeline stage. [*grin*]

Comment: Please don't under estimated the speed of the PowerShell pipeline. The point here is that you unfortunately can't really leverage from it as for the  `-Unique` switch you will need to stall the pipeline. (Meaning, **with** the `-Unique` parameter, the  **first** command is generally faster, **without** `-Unique` parameter, the **later** command is generally faster)

Comment: If you mean "better" in terms of performance, I would recommend you to look at your whole solution and not just to a single statement as **the performance of a complete (PowerShell) solution is supposed to be better than the sum of its parts**, see also: [Fastest Way to get a uniquely index item from the property of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59437162/1701026)

Comment: See also: [Select-Object -Unique is unnecessary slow and exhaustive #11221](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have an `$output` via some function (`gci` in your case) and you are interested in the field `$output.Matches`.

- If you run `$output | select Matches` (example 1), you run a
  `Foreach-Object` statement against every object in your array. This
  pipeline will use some RAM (very limited, indeed) that are used in a
  serial calculation, so every object of $output is processed one after
  the other.
- If you run `$output.Matches` (example 2), you select a field from an
  array. This will use a lot of RAM at once, but the field will be
  processed as one big object instead of many little objects.

As it comes to performance. As always, note that PowerShell is not the way to go if you need high performance. It was never designed to be a fast programming language.

When you're using small objects (like `gci $env:userprofile\Desktop`), the performance hit will be small. When using large objects or using a lot of nested pipes, the performance hit will be large.

I've just tested it with a `gci Z:\ -recurse` when Z:\ is a network drive. Performance is dropped with a factor of 20 in this specific case. (Use `Measure-Command` to test this.)