# fast line search in big array - powershell

Tags: powershell

I have some array (export from csv file) with ~ 100k lines . File size is ~ 22mb on disk
All i need is to find line with some data, process it and load to mssql (i need to sync csv data with mssql)

Problem is that search tooks almost 1 second (~ TotalMilliseconds : 655,0788)!

```
$csv.Where({$_.'Device UUID' -eq 'lalala'})
```

Any way just to speed it up?

Comment: Do you only ever need 1 line/row? Or can there be multiple matching rows?

Comment: If you need to search for multiple `$_.Device UUID`, you might consider to index your list using a hashtable: like `$HashTable[$_.Device UUID] = $_` first.

Comment: Related: [Fastest Way to get a uniquely index item from the property of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59437162/1701026)

Comment: the `Select-String` cmdlet can grab a file directly. so you may be able to feed your CSV to it, find the desired line, and then use that. converting the result into a structured object could be done with `ConvertFrom-Csv`.

Comment: Maybe it's time for a database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load all 100K rows into a hashtable, using the `Device UUID` property as the key - this will make it *much* faster to locate a row than by iterating the whole array with `.Where({...})`:

```
$deviceTable = @{}
Import-Csv .\path\to\device_list.csv |ForEach-Object {
  $deviceTable[$_.'Device UUID'] = $_
}
```

This will now take *significantly less than* 1 second:

```
$matchingDevice = $deviceTable['lalala']
```

Comment: thx, that method is fastest - 1- 10ms. indexof method like above - 60ms

Answer (score 1):

If you only need *one or a few lookups*, you can consider the following alternative to [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67036242/45375). Note that, like Mathias' solution, it *requires reading all rows into memory at once*:

```sh
# Load all rows into memory.
$allRows = Import-Csv file.csv

# Get the *index* of the row with the column value of interest.
# Note: This lookup is case-SENSITIVE.
$rowIndex = $allRows.'Device UUID'.IndexOf('lalala')

# Retrieve the row of interest by index, if found.
($rowOfInterest = if ($rowIndex -ne -1) { $allRows[$rowIndex] })
```

Once the rows are loaded into memory (as `[pscustomobject]` instances, which itself won't be fast), the array lookup - via [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) - is reasonably fast, thanks to *.NET* performing the (linear) array search, using the [`System.Array.IndexOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Array.IndexOf) method.

The problem with your `.Where({ ... })` approach is that iteratively calling a *PowerShell* script block (`{ ... }`) many times is computationally expensive.

---

It comes down to the following **trade-off**:

- **Either**: Spend more time *up front* to build up a data structure (`[hashtable]`) that allows *efficient lookup* (Mathias' answer)
- **Or**: Read the file more quickly, but spend more time on each lookup (this answer).

Answer (score 0):

Playing around with sqlite shell.

```
'Device UUID' | set-content file.csv
1..2200kb | % { get-random } | add-content file.csv # 1.44 sec, 25mb 

'.mode csv
.import file.csv file' | sqlite3 file  # 2.92 sec, 81mb


# last row
'select * from file where "device uuid" = 2143292650;' | sqlite3 file
# 'select * from file where "device uuid" > 2143292649 and "device uuid" < 2143292651;' | sqlite3 file

2143292650


(history)[-1] | % { $_.endexecutiontime - $_.startexecutiontime }

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 570
Ticks             : 5706795
TotalDays         : 6.60508680555556E-06
TotalHours        : 0.000158522083333333
TotalMinutes      : 0.009511325
TotalSeconds      : 0.5706795
TotalMilliseconds : 570.6795

# 34 ms after this:
# 'create index deviceindex on file("device uuid");' | sqlite3 file
# with ".timer on", it's 1ms, after the table is loaded
```