# PowerShell performance issue with Where-Object

Tags: powershell, performance, where-object

Is this behavior explainable?

```
PS C:\> $PosixGroups = Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter '(ObjectClass=posixGroup)' -Server $DomainController -Credential $cred -Properties gidNumber
PS C:\> $gid=500
PS C:\> $posixGroups.count
1049
PS C:\> Measure-Command {$found = $PosixGroups | Where-Object {$_.gidNumber -eq $gid}}

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 1
Seconds           : 42
Milliseconds      : 939
Ticks             : 1029394783
TotalDays         : 0.00119142914699074
TotalHours        : 0.0285942995277778
TotalMinutes      : 1.71565797166667
TotalSeconds      : 102.9394783
TotalMilliseconds : 102939.4783


PS C:\> Measure-Command {$found = $PosixGroups | Where-Object {$_.gidNumber -eq $gid}}

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 14
Ticks             : 141895
TotalDays         : 1.64230324074074E-07
TotalHours        : 3.94152777777778E-06
TotalMinutes      : 0.000236491666666667
TotalSeconds      : 0.0141895
TotalMilliseconds : 14.1895
```

Terrible performance at 1 minute 42 seconds the first time, then a subsequent repeat of the command completes in 14 milliseconds? I don't understand this, I haven't noticed anything like this before using Where-Object.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `Where-Object` and has everything to do with how the AD Module works. But yes, indeed, `Where-Object` performance is not the greatest.

Comment: How long does it take without the Where?

Comment: That's probably due to the [deferred execution (lazy evaluation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/linq/deferred-execution-lazy-evaluation) of the `Get-ADGroup` command and [caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)). See also: [Fastest Way to get a uniquely index item from the property of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59437162/1701026).